# How to draw a view over another by using Constraint Layout dynamically

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I need to achieve this dynamically. An `ImageView` and at the top it a `TextView.`

[image]

This is the code of this layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_facebook_login_pressed"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.672"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am trying to do this dynamically. This is what i do.

```
     ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll_seasonFragment);

     ImageView imageView= new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

     TextView textView= new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

     final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            int margin = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);

layout.addView(textView);
layout.addView(imageView);
```

This is adding `Views` one after other, I need to know how can i draw them over another.

**EDIT**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="551dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll_seasonFragment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is `ll_seasonFragment`? Can you post that XML?

Comment: @Cheticamp : I have put that code, there are no items in it

Comment: That clears things up a bit. The problem is with LinearLayout and your use of it. Do you need the LinearLayout or do you want to do everything with ConstraintLayout? You could just do as Jyoti Sharma suggests and use a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. If you don't need an internal layout, using just ConstraintLayout is preferred and can be done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replicate your layout through code, you don't need the linear layout. Just create a layout with an empty `ConstraintLayout` like this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This could also have been created through code. The following will add a centered `TextView` into this blank layout:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        textView.setText("This is a centered TextView");
        // Add view to the layout. Without constraints, they will all flop into the top
        // left corner of the layout.
        layout.addView(textView);

        // ConstraintSet will control all the connections between the views in the ConstraintLayout
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(layout);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START,
                              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END,
                              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP,
                              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
    }
}
```

The key idea here is the `ConstraintSet` that will create the constraints that are needed to place views in the right places. You can add and constrain your `ImageView` in much the same way.

I suggest that you stick with `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` instead of `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT`. Last time I checked, left and right were not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add relative layout in ConstraintLayout first and then add imageView and textview inside relative layout.